# Does anyone know how to get argument name automatically in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, ide, arguments

Look at the below-given image of Intellij IDEA -
[image: Automatic argument names(image of Intellij IDEA)]

When we use a function it automatically provides the argument name and when we copy a code-snippet then that argument name is not copied(it is just for our reference).

I want to do the same in my vs-code editor but, I can't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Inline Parameters for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters) extension you looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot That extension is very helpful, but do you know another extension which supports languages such as C/C++, Python, Java etc

Answer (score 2):

This feature, called "parameter hints", requires support from the language server, so whether or not this is currently supported varies from language to language.

For C++, clangd has experimental support for this (enabled by adding `--inlay-hints=true` to `"clangd.arguments"`) starting from clangd 13.

I'm not familiar with the status for other languages, so will let others answer on that front.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of VS Code, there they had given support for Parameter hint highlight [image] See the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62#_parameter-hint-highlight)

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for. This VSCode feature is about the parameter hint inside the **parameters tooltip**, not the parameter variable name displayed inline next to each parameter.